# MYSQL DELETE and Roll back

Tags: mysql

I have a problem.

Past month I have a user query:

```
DELETE 
FROM  table_name
WHERE name = 'test';
```

it deletes approx 100 rows which is working fine.

But now I need that the delete rows that were deleted are rolled back? Is there is any procedure to get all my rows back?

I am using mysql.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Restore a backup. You shouldn't delete rows you don't want to delete.

Comment: I would agree, if you are fundamentally changing the DB structure/data, once you purge that data you are out of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The rows are gone. MySQL has no built-in revision control constructs. If you are worried about this being a common occurrence, make sure to back up your database before you run these kinds of queries (look into `mysqldump`)

Comment: Or... don't use `DELETE` and use something like `Status` = `Deleted` or otherwise (knowing it can get much more complex than this).

Comment: @Jared: even then there's no way of saying "undo **just** my last action". You'd have to figure out somehow what was just marked as deleted the last time.

Comment: True, but at least now you are starting to see the issue involved in saving state.

Comment: yes,  i know rows are gone , but i want it back i think by using roll back we are able to get it back

Comment: @user872258 You can't rollback rows which are gone.

Comment: No, roll backs are for transactions. Unless you're not telling us something (are you using transactions??), rolling back won't save you.

Comment: ROLLBACK only works within a single transaction, which means you could restore rows a single DELETE command deleted (and this only if it was within a transaction). It won't help you restoring rows deleted during the course of entire month.

Comment: @Mchl excellent point. Yes, even with transactions once you commit a delete, it's still all gone. Backups or bust, I say.

Comment: Or like jetgrrl says, binlogs if they were enabled and there is a starting point for them available.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked in the mysqlbinlog?  There could still be something of value in there.

And I'm sure you'd have a backup that you could restore from? :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are lost, but in the future to prevent this:

From php.net using PDO

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

```
<?php
/* Begin a transaction, turning off autocommit */
$dbh->beginTransaction();

/* Change the database schema and data */
$sth = $dbh->exec("DROP TABLE fruit");
$sth = $dbh->exec("UPDATE dessert
    SET name = 'hamburger'");

/* Recognize mistake and roll back changes */
$dbh->rollBack();

/* Database connection is now back in autocommit mode */
?>
```